# How to create a hierarchical tree from array of strings Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tree, frontend

I am trying to create a file hierarchy tree from an array of strings, however I am not getting it quite right and I *know* it is terribly inefficient, but not sure how to make it better.

Given I have:

```
const paths = [
  "test_data/new_directory/ok.txt",
  "test_data/reads_1.fq",
  "test_data/test_ref.fa",
  "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt",
  "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt",
  "test_data/new_directory/file2.txt",
  "other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls",
  "other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls",
  "other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls",
  "third_dir/first.xls"
];
```

I would like to end up with the following object:

```
{
  "/other_dir": {
    path: "/other_dir",
    type: "folder",
    isRoot: true,
    children: ["/other_dir/dir2"]
  },
  "/other_dir/dir2": {
    path: "/other_dir/dir2",
    type: "folder",
    children: ["/other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls"]
  },
  "/other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls": {
    path: "/other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir": {
    path: "/other_dir/sub_dir",
    type: "folder",
    children: ["/other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls", "/other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls"]
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls": {
    path: "/other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls": {
    path: "/other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data": {
    path: "/test_data",
    type: "folder",
    isRoot: true,
    children: [
      "/test_data/dir2",
      "/test_data/new_directory",
      "/test_data/test_ref.fa",
      "/test_data/reads_1.fq"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2",
    type: "folder",
    children: ["/test_data/dir2/dir3", "/test_data/file2.txt"]
  },
  "/test_data/file2.txt": {
    path: "/test_data/file2.txt",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2/dir3",
    type: "folder",
    children: ["/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4"]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4",
    type: "folder",
    children: ["/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5"]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5",
    type: "folder",
    children: [
      "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt",
      "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt": {
    path: "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory": {
    path: "/test_data/new_directory",
    type: "folder",
    children: [
      "/test_data/new_directory/ok.txt",
      "/test_data/new_directory/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory/file2.txt": {
    path: "/test_data/new_directory/file2.txt",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory/ok.txt": {
    path: "/test_data/new_directory/ok.txt",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/reads_1.fq": {
    path: "/test_data/reads_1.fq",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/test_data/test_ref.fa": {
    path: "/test_data/test_ref.fa",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  },
  "/third_dir": {
    path: "/third_dir",
    type: "folder",
    isRoot: true,
    children: ["/third_dir/first.xls"]
  },
  "/third_dir/first.xls": {
    path: "/third_dir/first.xls",
    type: "file",
    children: []
  }
};
```

This is my attempt, and I have spent *way* too long on this

```
const buildChildNodes = (arr, root) => {
  let a = []

  arr.map((n, idx) => {
    a.push('/' + root + '/' + arr[idx])
  });
  return a;
}

const createTree = paths => {
  let finalTree = {};


  paths.map(path => {
    let tree = {};

    let subTree = path.split('/')
    subTree.forEach((a,i) => {
      tree = {}
      let root = subTree[0]

      tree.path = '/' + subTree.slice(0, i+1).join('/')
      tree.type = subTree.slice(i+1).length > 0 ? 'folder' : 'file'
      if(i === 0){
        tree.isRoot = true
      }
      tree.children = buildChildNodes(subTree.slice(i+1), root)

      finalTree['/' + subTree.slice(0, i+1).join('/')] = tree
    })



  })
  return finalTree;
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(createTree(paths.sort()), null, 2));
```

And this is what I end up with, as you can see, the children nodes are not being created correctly:

```
{
  "/other_dir": {
    "path": "/other_dir",
    "type": "folder",
    "isRoot": true,
    "children": [
      "/other_dir/sub_dir",
      "/other_dir/file2.xls"
    ]
  },
  "/other_dir/dir2": {
    "path": "/other_dir/dir2",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/other_dir/newfile.xls"
    ]
  },
  "/other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls": {
    "path": "/other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir": {
    "path": "/other_dir/sub_dir",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/other_dir/file2.xls"
    ]
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls": {
    "path": "/other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls": {
    "path": "/other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data": {
    "path": "/test_data",
    "type": "folder",
    "isRoot": true,
    "children": [
      "/test_data/test_ref.fa"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/test_data/dir3",
      "/test_data/dir4",
      "/test_data/dir5",
      "/test_data/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2/dir3",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/test_data/dir4",
      "/test_data/dir5",
      "/test_data/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/test_data/dir5",
      "/test_data/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/test_data/file2.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt": {
    "path": "/test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory": {
    "path": "/test_data/new_directory",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
      "/test_data/ok.txt"
    ]
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory/file2.txt": {
    "path": "/test_data/new_directory/file2.txt",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data/new_directory/ok.txt": {
    "path": "/test_data/new_directory/ok.txt",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data/reads_1.fq": {
    "path": "/test_data/reads_1.fq",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/test_data/test_ref.fa": {
    "path": "/test_data/test_ref.fa",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  },
  "/third_dir": {
    "path": "/third_dir",
    "type": "folder",
    "isRoot": true,
    "children": [
      "/third_dir/first.xls"
    ]
  },
  "/third_dir/first.xls": {
    "path": "/third_dir/first.xls",
    "type": "file",
    "children": []
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me out on this I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the sub parts of the strings, check if the path exits or add a new path. Then take the previous path and add the childrens.

```js
const
    paths = ["test_data/new_directory/ok.txt", "test_data/reads_1.fq", "test_data/test_ref.fa", "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt", "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt", "test_data/new_directory/file2.txt", "other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls", "other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls", "other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls", "third_dir/first.xls"],
    result = paths.sort().reduce((r, p) => {
        p.split(/\//).forEach((_, i, p) => {
            var path = '/' + p.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');
            r[path] = r[path] || { path, type: i + 1 === p.length ? 'file' : 'folder', children: [] };
            if (i)  {
                const prev = '/' + p.slice(0, i).join('/');
                if (!r[prev].children.includes(path)) r[prev].children.push(path);
            } else {
                r[path].isRoot = true;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you soooo much!!  You have really helped me out!  Out of curiosity, how long did it take you to figure this out?  Obviously it was very quick since I just asked it.  I need to get better at data structures.  Thank you again!!

Comment: ususally it goes fast, but what your data and the wanted result was abit differetn for figure out. then you ask for a tree, but the result is a flat node reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested `reduce` method where you add path to the children array only if there is next part of the path (which means that the current elements has child) and also if that child is not included already in the array.

```js
const paths = [
  "test_data/new_directory/ok.txt",
  "test_data/reads_1.fq",
  "test_data/test_ref.fa",
  "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt",
  "test_data/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.txt",
  "test_data/new_directory/file2.txt",
  "other_dir/dir2/newfile.xls",
  "other_dir/sub_dir/file1.xls",
  "other_dir/sub_dir/file2.xls",
  "third_dir/first.xls"
];

const result = paths.reduce((acc, e) => {
  let prev = ''

  e.split('/').reduce((r, path, i, a) => {
    prev += '/' + path;

    if (!r[prev]) {
      const children = []
      const type = a[i + 1] ? 'folder' : 'file'
      const obj = { path: prev, type, children }

      if (i == 0) {
        obj.isRoot = true
      }

      r[prev] = obj
    }

    if (a[i + 1]) {
      const child = prev + '/' + a[i + 1];
      if (!r[prev].children.includes(child)) {
        r[prev].children.push(child)
      }
    }

    return r
  }, acc)

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```